# How to be notified when a TextEditor loses focus?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14

In my SwiftUI app, I would like to be notified when the `TextEditor` loses focus/has finished editing. Ideally, something like `TextField`'s `onCommit` callback would be perfect.

Using the new `onChange` as below does work for receiving every new character that the user types, but I really want to know when they are finished.

```swift
@State var notes = ""
...

TextEditor(text: $notes)
    .onChange(of: notes, perform: { newString in
        print(newString)
    })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out, you can use the `UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification`.

```swift
TextEditor(text: $notes)
    .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification)) { _ in
        print("done editing!")
    }
```

Comment: This does not work if you have a form and focus moves to next editable field without hiding keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

On iOS 15.0, there is now [@FocusState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate).

```
struct MyView: View {

  @State var text: String
  @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

  var body: some View {
    Form {
      TextEditor(text: $text)
        .focused($isFocused)
        .onChange(of: isFocused) { isFocused in
          // do stuff based off focus state change
        }
    }
  }
}
```